# use sudo -s but show current folder name

Tags: macos, sudo, terminal

Is there a way to use `sudo -s`but keeping the current folder name in prompt?

[image: terminal]

I want to see `jw:documents nescalante$` instead of `bash-3.2#` when using `sudo -s`.

Thanks!

Comment: You start to use other user (root) so you are located in root's home. There is no reason you can't change to the directory you want. Or use full power of sudo and run command directly with sudo w/o need of use root shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `sudo -s` you obtain a behaviour similar to `sudo /bin/bash`.
The variable *USER* is set to `root` and not anymore to `nescalante`.

You can put inside your `.bashrc` or, worst, in your `.bash_aliases` an IF THEN block to set your prompt when you are the root user.

```
if [ "$USER" = "root" ]
then
  export PS1="\[\e[36;1m\]\u@\[\e[32;1m\]\h \[\e[34;1m\]\w> \[\e[0m\]"
fi
```

If you do not want to know that you are root in that shell you can write

```
  export PS1="\[\e[36;1m\]HowIWantToBe@\[\e[32;1m\]\h \[\e[34;1m\]\w> \[\e[0m\]"
```

but **I strongly suggest to leave notice that you are root**. `root` can delete a system with a single command line, in so many way that you cannot even image :).

Note:

- If you use a *shell* different from `bash` you have to write with a different syntax in a file different from `.bashrc`.
- You can search the prompt PS1 value currently in use for your user in your shell starting file (e.g. `.bashrc`) and copy/modify it as you wish.
- If you want to know better how `sudo` and `su` commands function refer to man pages or give a fast look e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/a/771523/257269).