# $HOME environment variable is not automatically set

Tags: linux, bash

I have an user that I created using

```
adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --home /home/myuser myuser
```

The corresponding line in /etc/passwd looks like:

```
myuser:x:106:65534::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

When I login as this user by running `sudo -u myuser bash`, I get the error

```
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Indeed, `echo $HOME` gives me `/root/`. So each time I log in as this user, I have to run `export HOME=/home/myuser` manually, otherwise many program won't run correctly. I have added this line to the .profile, .bash_profile, and .bashrc of this user (just in case), but nothing to do.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can give a look [here](http://superuser.com/a/771523/257269) to see different ways to do `sudo` or `su` and different effect on  `$HOME` , `$USER`,  `Env.`, and `$PATH`. It's about the root user but it works for other users too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *aren't* logging in as that user. `sudo` only changes your security credentials (UID, GID...), at most it calls a few PAM session modules, but that's still not a real "login" (and neither is `su` nor even `su -l`, really).

In particular, `sudo` is frequently configured to keep the original home directory for convenience, as many people use `sudo -s` for root privileges but want to keep their regular ~/.vimrc and such.

There is the `sudo -H` option to force setting $HOME, and the `sudo -i` option to run the shell in "login" mode (to let it read .bash_profile), but neither of those will amount to a full login anyway. To properly log in as that user, try `ssh myuser@localhost`, or just do it from the regular login prompt.