# Running sudo python and python as SU use two different versions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, sudo

I understand `sudo` doesn't run a command as the current user, but I don't understand why the two following commands produce differing outputs:

Case 1:

```
user@.../folder$ sudo python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Case 2:

```
user@.../folder$ sudo su
(base) root@.../folder# python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/771523/432690) under the linked duplicate analyzes `$PATH` among other things. Your `$PATH`s may vary but the point is `sudo` and `su` use different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your normal user has a different shell environment than root. Your first command:

```
sudo python
```

is your regular environment.

```
user@.../folder$ sudo su
(base) root@.../folder# python
```

Is your root user environment. Try executing the command `env` in both environments and you should see plenty of differences. The different python version is probably due to a difference in the $PATH variable. You can see which python you're using with `type -a python`

Comment: `regular environment` -- Not likely. Usually `sudo` is configured *not* to preserve the calling user's environment.